# Installing xcache on a shared hosting account

Tags: php, apache, shared-hosting, opcode, xcache

I'd like to install xcache on a shared hosting account. I've followed the instructions here: http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/InstallFromSource but note the differences:

- You can not run "su" on a shared host, since the make install wants to move the xcache.* files to a shared module directory.
- You can, however, copy the xcache.* files into a directory on your account and tell php.ini to use that library

The problem I'm having is the following php error:

```
[30-Jan-2013 04:35:52 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: XCache: Unable to    initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
```

This shared host uses several php versions. I'd like to target a specific php binary as reference for compilation.

On my server:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/php/53/etc
Loaded Configuration File   /home4/scoobydo/public_html/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /usr/php/53/etc/php.d
```

How do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, if you cannot run 'su', then you cannot make & make install xcache for installation from source.

You might be able to from pre-compiled binaries for your distro but again, these probably need a 'su' or 'sudo' command to be installed.